# CSS3 Selector missing :contains

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

I have problem in selecting links from a web document which contains word "FooBar".

I tried `A:contains('FooBar')` on selector test and it worked however it doesn't work from my jsoup application which is based on CSS3 selectors.

selector test: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/trysel.asp?filename=trysel_basic&jqsel=p.intro,%23choose

seems like CSS3 doesn't support :contains  http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#content-selectors

any alternative to :contains in CSS3?

Comment: Selecting in your CSS or your jQuery? Please show the relevant code

Comment: jsoup is not jQuery. Please do not get the two mixed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `:contains` was removed from the CSS3 spec, and that no browsers currently support it.

If you want to select an anchor element with an `href` containing "FooBar", you can use something like this:

```
a[href*="FooBar"] {
  // your styles here
}
```

This selector works on any attribute and is supported in all major browsers, including IE7+.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/3Jf9Q/).

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) (and more specifically [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)) has extended the CSS selectors with its own custom selectors. `:contains` is a custom selector.